# My laptop does strange behaviors, what could be the reason?

Tags: laptop, shutdown, reboot, issue-tracking

I bought a used laptop and it doesn't shutdown. It only restarts. I mean after shutting it down it powers on automatically and immediately.

- If I'm on windows (after booting into windows), I have to press and
  hold the power button for a few seconds (force shutdown) to shut it
  down without the automatic turn.
- If I'm not on windows (before booting), I can press the  power button
  (the quick press, not pressing and holding) and it will shut down
  properly too.

I tried to install a new windows but the same issue happens.

Another issue that could be related to the restarting issue is that the laptop may give a black screen while charging and I have to restart it using long press on the power button.

Laptop model: Dell Precession M6500 Core i7

**Edit:**

I use Windows 10

I tried *shutdown -s* but it didn't solve the issue.

Thank you so much,

Comment: Since you are on Windows, do mention the Windows version. What if you open a command prompt as admin and run the command    shutdown -s ?

Comment: @patkim It's windows 10 and I tried shutdown -s but it still restarts instead of shutting down.

Comment: Create a Live linux bootable USB and boot thru it, it will run as a Live OS without getting installed from the memory. Now try shutting down from Linux and see how it behaves. If you have Windows 10 USB/DVD installer boot thru it, go to repair options and just select shut down computer and see how it behaves.

Comment: @patkim Wow those are great ideas... I didn't think of that. I'll try it right now and I'll  inform you in the comments.

Comment: @patkim I tried a live Linux and it didn't shutdown. It restarts too.

Comment: In Windows 10 power options also just disable Fast Startup and see if it makes any difference. Any idea how old the machine could be? Can't conclude from here, but since it also happened with Linux, it might hint at possibly some hardware issue, just a thought right now.

Comment: @I don't really know but the machine could be old. Thanks to your troubleshooting steps, I understand that this is more likely to be a hardware issue. Thank you for helping me :) I'll try to do more investigation.

Comment: Try to update BIOS.

Comment: Reason I ask is check if there's any BIOS update for that model and if so, just as one more try update BIOS and see if that makes any difference. It appears it's old model and comes with Windows 7 preinstalled.

Comment: I'd have to agree with the BIOS check, I'm pretty sure I have seen some BIOS updates that do mention fixing reboot/shutdown issues...

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help me. The touch bad of the laptop suddenly didn't work today. So, I returned the laptop back to the shop . They didn't want to take it as they already know it has major issues. I finally managed to return it by not receiving it's full cost. They kept some money as fees. I was deceived!